# Newbie here.. How to start with EOS?

Tags: decentralization

How good is EOS comparatively to ETH?
Provide some best references what and why & How questions about EOS?

Comment: There is no indication of the author's knowledge of ETH to be comparing it to EOS. This seems an attempt to speculate on the price of EOS depending on its relative advantages over ETH. The question could be more specific to be addressed by the community here.

Comment: Related: [Fundamentally what is the difference between the EOS and Ethereum platforms?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72756/1652)

Answer (score 2):

EOS's advantages are basically this:

-Millions of tps thanks to interblockchain-communication & multi-threading
free transactions will boost adoption.

-More decentralized than ETH or BTC: 21 BPs vs a few mining pools.

-First blockchain with a constitution.

-First blockchain with built-in arbitration system.

-Account recovery incase you lose private key.

-Security delayed transactions lower risk of theft.

-500 ms blocktime through BFT-dPOS consensus.

-1 second irreversibility for cross-chain transfers.

-2-5% inflation will fund dapps & deveopement indefinitely.

-No resources are wasted on mining but reinvested in the ecosystem.

-Eos tokens are blockchain real-estate and represent ownership of a share of the network.

-Prevents forking by built-in voting.

-Easy bug-fixing for dapp developers

Comment: Can you include the original source/link of your quotes?

Comment: I made this quote and providing sources to everything would be too long and won't fit.

Comment: Got this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/8g768p/eos_dont_believe_the_hype/dy9fj1i/) with the same points from 8 days ago, which is quoting from some other source.